# crash screen customization with react-native-exception-handler

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am working on a project that contains react-native-exception-handler: https://github.com/a7ul/react-native-exception-handler

in the documentation of the library it vaguely explains how "" "" "" customize "" "" "the popup that tells the user that there was a native error.

my experience developing native android is not much, therefore my knowledge in java is little.

Performing the steps indicated in the documentation of the library, I am not achieving the result I want: Show a popup with a message for the user when a native error occurs.

In a 2018 post, a user indicated that they could modify / swap the native component of the library popup using Intents:

/android/app/src/java/com/MainApplication

```
  ReactNativeExceptionHandlerModule.setNativeExceptionHandler(new NativeExceptionHandlerIfc() {
      @Override
      public void handleNativeException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable, Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler originalHandler) {
          Context context = getApplicationContext();
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, CustomExceptionHandler.class);
          context.startActivity(intent);
      }
  });
```

The intent would call an activity defined as follows:

```
package com.projectname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CustomExceptionHandler extends Activity {
    private Button quitButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.custom_error_screen);

        quitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eh_quit_button);

        quitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

custom error display is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="The application crashed unexpectedly"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="Contact us: " />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="https://playersupport.tryoliver.com" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eh_quit_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="QUIT" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eh_stack_trace_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#EEE"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

also defined in the application manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".CustomExceptionHandler" />
```

When I get a native error in my reactive app, all I get is an interface freeze.

In the implementation that I do, what am I missing? And if nothing is missing, then what happens?

I hope that my application by using this library can show a custom popup for when a native error occurs.

I am grateful to anyone who shares a bit of their knowledge with me.